xhtml2pdf: Custom font is not adopted and remains with Helvetica
I have the problem that I cannot change the font in xhtml2pdf (I have my own font (Akkurat) that I want to integrate) it always remains Helvetica.
The style rules:
TEXT_HTML_STYLE: Final[str] = f"""  
<head>
<style>

@font-face {{
    font-family: 'Akkurat';
    src: url('/static/fonts/Akkurat.ttf');
}}

@page {{
    size: A4;
    @frame header_frame {{        
        -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
    }}
    @frame content_frame {{
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 682pt;
    }}
    @frame footer_frame {{
        -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 800pt; height: 20pt;
    }}
}}

body {{
    margin: 1cm;
    font-family: 'Akkurat';
}}
</style>
</head>"""

The Python functionality to assemble the HTML:
def generate_html(html_text) -> str:
    return f"""
            <html>
            {TEXT_HTML_STYLE}
                <body>
                    <div id="footer_content">Page <pdf:pagenumber> of <pdf:pagecount>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                {html_text}
                </body>
            </html>
            """

The document is later converted to a PDf, which causes no problems.

@kJ thanks for your answer, I thought so too but I use the font in many places in my application (in my CSS for the HTML page) it works there too
